# Commands or Audit collection used to determin actions taken on an object

Tags: design-patterns, command, audit

Given a client application that consumes a rest API, is there an existing pattern or approach for delivering a collection of 'actions, events, commands' along with a data payload that represents the actions that were taken to mutate the payload to the state it is in?

So, if page is loaded with a (pseudo code - also assume GUIDs are on the object...not listing them here for brevity.

```
GET house/76 => {house: {frontDoor: { open: false, locked: true } } }
```

And the client has a form that allows you to mutate that object where the following is the POST

```
POST: {house: {frontDoor: { open: true, locked: false } } }
```

and the associated action log would be something like

```
[{ OpenedDoor: id }, {UnlockedDoor: id }]
```

Given the collection of actions you could then rebuild the state of the original object to its mutated state, or audit the actions to take other actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the pattern you are looking for is called [Event Sourcing](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html). It explicitly mentions auditing as one of its use cases. The quintessential example of event sourcing is a version control system.

Comment: related: [Capturing the World in Software](https://blog.jessitron.com/2020/01/24/capturing-the-world-in-software/)